# Creating custom ball physics with SceneKit swift

Tags: swift, scenekit

I have a particular scene I'm trying to create.

Objects of varying size should spawn outside the visible area and congregate at the center of the scene.

- The objects should begin traveling with varying velocity.
- Collisions should affect trajectory but the objects should still meet
  at the center.
- The effect should be no different than balls in a funnel, except the z position does not change.

Any high level guidance would be greatly appreciated as I am a bit unfamiliar with the framework.

Additionally, objects should be selectable, and the amount of spawned objects should be no more than 20.

Again to reiterate, I'm looking for any high level guidance towards creating the physics and object behavior as I realize this is a bit of an involved question. So any help at all is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've since solved this and will post an answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using SceneKit, I opted to using UIKitDynamics to add physical effects to the views.

With UIKitDynamics all there is to do is,

a) create UIDynamicAnimator

b) define a field behavior (in my case radial)

c) define collision behavior for the objects

The implementation is a bit involved, so I'll link a repo demonstrating the end result shortly.